# Beautiful Soup error - not "seeing" entire web page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape some simple web links off [this stats canada webpage](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2006/dp-pd/tbt/Geo-index-eng.cfm?TABID=5&LANG=E&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=0&GID=0&GK=0&GRP=1&PID=99015&PRID=0&PTYPE=88971,97154&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2006&THEME=70&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0#L1G774507). I want to get all the links which are of class "indent-3" and type li. I thought the code for that would be the following:

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

#stats canada webpage
base_page = ("http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2006/dp-pd/tbt/Geo-index-eng.cfm?TABID=5&LANG=E&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=0&GID=0&GK=0&GRP=1&PID=99015&PRID=0&PTYPE=88971,97154&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2006&THEME=70&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0")

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request(base_page) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

links = soup.find_all("li", class_="indent-3")
```

But when I run this code, links is a list of length 13 when it should be of length 288. And when I do

```
soup.get_text()
```

soup only retrieves text from a very small portion of the webpage. Up to Brackley which is entry number 428 on the page.

Why am I not getting most of the webpage?

Edit: since it seems like BeautifulSoup is not the issue, I tried saving the html file of the website as webfile.html. Then I read it directly into python.

```
f = file("webfile.html", 'r')
page = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
links = soup.find_all("li", class_="indent-3")
```

I am still only getting 13 links. I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It is not about `BeautifulSoup`, it is about the request you make.

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and providing `User-Agent` header worked for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#stats canada webpage
base_page = "http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2006/dp-pd/tbt/Geo-index-eng.cfm?TABID=5&LANG=E&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=0&GID=0&GK=0&GRP=1&PID=99015&PRID=0&PTYPE=88971,97154&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2006&THEME=70&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0"

response = requests.get(base_page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

links = soup.find_all("li", class_="indent-3")
print len(links)  # prints 288
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I find `User-Agent` for my browser and why is this necessary to extract the webpage?

Comment: @Ben one option would be to use browser developer tools and see the request headers being made by your browser. It can be an anti-web-scraping technique used by the website.